# How can I properly organize structs in Rust to minimize mutable borrow problem?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust for very long, and I don't have experience with C++. I've always worked with garbage-collected languages like Java and Go. The issue that troubles me the most in coding is the  E0502 errors. When designing and implementing a module's functionality, I often come across situations like the following:

```
struct Segment{

}

struct Cache{

}

struct LogInner{
    segments: Vec<Segment>,
    cache: Cache
}

impl LogInner {
    fn read(&mut self, offset: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
        let idx = self.find_segment_index(offset);
        let segment = &self.segments[idx];
        self.push_cache(segment);

        // load bytes from segment and return
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn find_segment_index(&self, offset: usize) -> usize {
        // seek the index of the segment which contains the given offset
        2
    }

    fn push_cache(&mut self, segment: &Segment) {
        // put segment into cache
    }
}
```

Compiler: [E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable.

In terms of experience from other languages, the design of this struct wouldn't be considered unreasonable. However, when I write Rust, this kind of situation occurs very frequently.
In fact, if we tackle each issue on a case-by-case basis, there is always a solution to be found. For example, with the code mentioned earlier:

1. The borrowing of the Vec could be delayed until within the push_cache function, by changing the push_cache function's parameter to an index of the Vec.
2. The push_cache could be removed, directly pasting its contents where it was originally called.
3. The parameter of the push_cache function could be changed to a raw pointer.
4. The Cache could be passed in from the outside as an argument.

But if these solutions are applied to an actual project, there seem to be many issues: loss of encapsulation, introduction of unnecessary computations, poor readability, etc.
Most importantly, my previous programming habits have not made me realize that it is a mistake for a struct method to have a parameter that is a reference to a field of the struct. Are there any best practices or design patterns that can help me better prevent or deal with such issues?